# PS3 account change

Tags: ps3

How do i change account details from one user to another.
I created the account then set up account and let my daughter play her game and then created extra users to find that she is now set up under my name.  How do i change it from hers to mine without her losing everything she has done

Answer (score 3):

- To Log off your current user account, simply go to *Account Management* under *Playstation Network* press triangle and choose sign out. You can remove the saved password and it won't sign on to your user afterwards.
- You can log on to the same *PSN account* on different users, a user only separates media and saves but account data such as address and billing history is saved per account, therefore if you wish to remove your account from your daughter's user, you can do so without her losing the saves.
- If you wish to copy her saves to a different system user, you can do so by by using the *Save Data Utility* under *Game*, note however that some game saves are locked to a single PSN account and cannot be copied. In any case, trophy progress will be disabled when playing a save copied from another account

More info on account, sub accounts and users can be found [here](http://ps3explained.com/beginner/users-accounts-and-sub-accounts/)

Comment: Hi JohnoBoy, Thanks but how do I remove the PSN from her name and re add it to my name, appreciate the help :-)

Comment: Hi, I will amend my answer as soon as I have access to my PS3